# how to get alerts when any changes or updates made in the database using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to database and hibernate. I created student registration project and I need to get alert or any message when there is a record inserted into a student personal table. so that i can get the email id from that newly inserted record and send welcome or some message to the student.I have done the sending message part. Now I need to learn about getting alerts when any changes happens in the database, it will helpful to maintain whole database for me.Hope this will enough.

Some says Hibernate Envers is useful and some says using triggers in mysql will help. Please advise the easiest way to get alerts using hibernate.

Comment: On DB side you can use triggers

Comment: Am using hibernate to map tables in the database. So i need to do this from Java side.

Comment: Hi mahesh for particular student registration page you can put email functionlaity while insert any record  in student so you can easily track you database changes.

Comment: Thank you Vishal, If it is done automated then i can have weekly,monthly reports of the changes or updates happened in the database. For that main purpose i need to execute via codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the [EmptyInterceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html) class and implement the `onFlushDirty` method

```
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object obj, Serializable id, Object[] newValues, Object[] oldValues, String[] properties, Type[] types) throws CallbackException {
    if (obj instanceof Student) {
          // send email alert...
```

The interceptor is used when creating the Session:

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession(interceptor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA2 callback-annotation(If your server is the only instance which is writing to the DB):

http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/annotations/callback

In your case postpersist and/or postupdate

```
@Entity
public class Student{
    @PostPersist 
    public void onPostPersist() {
         sendMsg();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you save or update a record,**the execute result will be recognized immediately**;thus if executing successfully(record saved or updated) you could then send message to the user.why bother to let hibernate to alert you.

As to the weekly or monthly reports of the database ,you could just add add additional fields to achieve that.For the student info,you add `create_time` and `update_time`,and then use some SQL aggregate function to generate the report.